# Issue closing menu on scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to close the nav dropdown menu on scroll but I don't think I am targeting the class on the button correctly with jQuery as it is not working.
I am trying to target the `.nav-menu-list` class.

**main.js and index.html**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $('.nav-menu-list').prev().dropdown("toggle");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="navbar-toggleable-md sticky clearfix fixed ">
  <header id="topNav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <nav>
          <ul class="desktop-nav-links ">
             <li class="list-group-item" >
                <a href="/"> Home </a>
             </li>
             <li class="list-group-item">
                <button class="dropdown-toggle nav-menu-list" type="button" id="" data- 
                    toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="content"> Content </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

At first I tried using `$('.dropdown-toggle').prev().dropdown("toggle");` which worked and closed the menu on scroll. The issue this gave me though was that it also targeted all of the dropdown-toggles on the page causing things to break.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated, thank you.

**Update**

After trying a few different ways of targeting the open dropdown menu to close on scroll, I found the best way for me was to explicitly target the class when the menu dropdown is open using -

`$('li.show .nav-menu-list').dropdown("toggle");`

So it is going to target the dropdown that is open.

Thank you everyone for helping me with this issue.

Comment: Is this a framework? Some contain js hooks for navigation closing behaviors.

Comment: Yes, it is a Django project.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? What version?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

To target a class in jQuery, you must specify a class selector:

```
$('.nav-menu-list').prev().dropdown("toggle");
```

Note the leading `.` in front of `nav-menu-list`, which you were missing.

Comment: Oh I am very sorry, that was just a typo when typing the question out. Sorry, I will correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me with this issue.

After trying a few different ways of targeting the open dropdown menu to close on scroll, I found the best way for me was to explicitly target the class when the menu dropdown is open with

`$('li.show .nav-menu-list').dropdown("toggle");`

So it is only going to be on the dropdown that is open.

I will add as an update to my question.

I hope this may also help anyone else with similar issues